# Как увеличить диапазон данных столбцов в сводной таблице pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Есть следующая сводная таблица:

[image: Кусок сводной таблицы]

Код данной таблицы:

```
data_pt = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['Раздел_ГКПЗ', 'Завод', 'Номер лота', '№ материала', 'Краткий текст позиции', 'ЕИ'], values=['Количество'], columns=['Дата поставки'], aggfunc=np.sum).sort_values(by=['Краткий текст позиции'])
```

Как видно из скриншота, диапазон дат - с февраля по ноябрь. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы этот диапазон всегда был, например, с декабря 2019 по декабрь 2020? Вне зависимости от дат, указанных в исходных данных.

Comment: Что с "кодом данной таблицы"? Это головоломка такая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего добавить строки с заведомо несуществующей позицией (например «AAA») так чтобы добавилось по одной строке за каждую дату, которая должна присутствовать в результате. И сделать все это надо **до вызова pivot_table**. Таким образом после вызова pivot_table у вас будут присутствовать все необходимые столбцы  и одна дополнительная строка с несуществующей позицией. Эту строку нужно будет удалить.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Ваш совет очень помог, удалять строку я не стал, воспользовался фильтром и в конечную таблицу она не попадает, но диапазон месяцев остаётся тем, который мне нужен.